# Issue with nagios monitoring

Tags: nagios

I need some help with Nagios monitoring.

I installed on server and agents but when I go to main screen I see only two services being monitored and what is says is that two services in "Critical"

I have attached screenshots for the same but what is says is the below two services monitored on agents ?? I thought they should be eight ?
Current Users
CPU Load

The following services are critical with command not found error:
SH Monitoring -- NRPE: Command 'check_ssh' not defined
FTP Monitoring-- NRPE: Command 'check_ftp' not defined

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [root@agent2 libexec]# ./check_ssh puppet
SSH OK - OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.025016s;;;0.000000;10.000000
[root@agent2 libexec]# ./check_ssh Xubuntu
SSH OK - OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.025308s;;;0.000000;10.000000
[root@agent2 libexec]# pwd
/usr/local/nagios/libexec
[root@agent2 libexec]#

If I can do ssh from Nagios server to agents why does the UI say NRPE: Command 'check_ssh' not defined  ??

Answer (score 0):

Check ssh and check ftp are external commands so I had to delete check_nrpe| from client side to make it work. Secondly I had to also install FTP Server for FTP monitoring to work. All good now.